# s3cmd asking for S3 URI while using s3cmd get

Tags: 14.04, command-line, backup, mysql, aws

I have uploaded a mysql backup file onto amazon s3 `s3://bucketname/object/mysqlbackupfile`. When i am trying to retrieve it using `s3cmd get s3://bucketname/object/mysqlbackupfile` there is an error popping up "ERROR: Parameter problem: Expecting S3 URI instead of '-'
". Can anyone help me with this. I am using ubuntu 14.04 lts and i'm trying this from a scaleway server.

Comment: I am NOT USING LOCALHOST.  I'm using a scaleway server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use, the regular aws cli? I never had any problem with it, and maintained by the provider. I recommend it because I had some issues with s3cmd.

You can install it easily with `pip install awscli`, then just run `aws configure` (where you have to enter some config details and credentials). If you don't have pip installed, you can just install it with `sudo apt-get install python-pip`.

Right after that, you'll have a tool with a little bit wider functionality like multiple accounts and regions.

If you want download your file, run:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/folder/file /local/folder/file
```

For uploading you can use:

```
aws s3 cp /local/folder/file s3://bucketname/folder/file
```

If you want to copy an entire directory recursively, just use locations and the --recursive option:

```
aws s3 cp /local/folder/ s3://bucketname/folder/ --recursive
```

If you also want to keep your local files and do a sync between the local folder and the s3 bucket, you can use:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucketname/folder /local/fodler
```

And it also have a great "help" functionality: `aws help` or `aws <command> help`.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much sir. :-) aws cli is the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the endpoint of s3 bucket.
Ex URL: bucketname.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com

You can obtain this URL in s3 properties.

use the URL instead of bucket name to download.

Comment: The end point of bucket contains only the link to that particular file which is of no use since it uses https. And also i tried using that link with `s3cmd get` it errors expecting S3 URI.

Comment: The syntax which you are using doesn't seem to be correct
The standard syntax is:
s3cmd get s3://BUCKET/OBJECT LOCAL_FILE